# Automatical creation of indentity(1,1) but with GUIDs instead of integers

Tags: sql, identity, guid

A neat thingy is to put *identity(2,3)* on a column to get the counter and an unique value to index. I wonder if, and in such case how, it's possible to do the same with a guid.

So, instead of inserting a row with *newid()*, I'd have one created for me.

If there's no way to do that, I'd like to know the technical rationale behind it. If there is any, of course.

```
create table Records (
  Id int identity(3,14) primary key,
  Occasion datetime not null,
  Amount float not null,
  Mileage int not null,
  Information varchar(999) default ' '
)
```

Comment: Beware, however, the horrorshow that is tables clustered on GUID. There be dragons of the first order.

Comment: @onupdatecascade Dragons be bad, bery, bery baaad. Especially of the first order. Keeping in mind that I'm not a DBA, would you care to describe such a dragon to be in more technical terms, e.g. by an example or something. I know it's a bit complex sometimes but I'd appreciate greatly some head-up.

Comment: Might be tough to pack into a comment, but here goes: GUIDs, while fine and useful, have severe scalability "gotchas" as indexing structures in SQL Server. Each table in SQL Server can be a heap or a "clustered index." A clustered index is best practice, in general, because it puts the table into a B Tree, which is searchable. However, B Trees organized on GUID values instead of INTs are VERY inefficient in SQL Server. There are problems with distributed inserts, use of RAM, index fragmentation, performance generally. In short: scalability problems.

Comment: @onupdatecascade Thanks - I appreciate the heads-up. I'll be aware of those dragons, hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the <s>lazy</s> efficient @MartinSmith commented (but didn't bother to formulate a full-size reply, forcing me to do that for him, hehe), we can use *default* keyword to achieve the requested behavior as shown below.

```
create table Records (
  Id uniqueidentifier primary key default newid(),
  Occasion datetime not null,
  Amount float not null,
  Mileage int not null,
  Information varchar(999) default ' '
)
```

And if the said lazy Martin wishes, he might just copy over the contents of this answer and post it as his own reply, since it was really his suggestions and I'm merely a typing machine for him. Given that he's got rep like an immortal God, I doubt he will, but still - I want to make this perfectly clear.